# Rigid analytic projective line is affinoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-geometry, projective-space, rigid-analytic-spaces

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, complete with respect to a nonarchimedean valuation. Chapter 2 of the book "Rigid Analytic Geometry and Its Applications" by Fresnel and Van der Put begins with the definition of affinoid subsets of the projective line $\mathbb P^1(K)=K$ $\cup$ {$\infty$}. The definitions are as follows:

An open disk $D \subset \mathbb P^1$ is a subset that has the form: {$z \in K :  \vert z - a \vert < r$}
with $a \in K$ and $r \in  \vert K^* \vert $ or {$z \in K : \vert z - a \vert > r$} $ \cup $ {$\infty $}. We will for simplicity
write {$z \in \mathbb P^1 :  \vert z - a \vert < r$} or {$z \in \mathbb P^1 : \vert z - a \vert > r$}. The deﬁnition of a
closed disk is obtained from the above by replacing < and > by $\leq$ and $\geq$.
We note that the terminology is somewhat misleading since an open disk (and
similarly a closed disk) is both open and closed in the ordinary topology of $\mathbb P^1$.
A connected affinoid subset of $\mathbb P^1$ is the complement of a non-empty ﬁnite union
of open disks. An aﬂinoid subset of $\mathbb P^1$ is a ﬁnite union of connected aﬂinoid
subsets. The empty set is (in general) also considered an afﬁnoid subset.

According to these definitions, the closed disk $B:=${$z \in \mathbb P^1 :  \vert z \vert \leq 1$} is a connected affinoid (its complement being the open disk {$z \in \mathbb P^1 :  \vert z \vert > 1$}) and $C:=${$z \in \mathbb P^1 :  \vert z \vert \geq 1$} is a connected affinoid (its complement being the open disk {$z \in \mathbb P^1 :  \vert z \vert < 1$}).

> > Hence $\mathbb P^1$ is an affinoid subset of itself, being the union of the two connected affinoids $B$ and $C$.

Now Chapter $2$ of said book is intended to build intuition for the more technical Chapters $3$ and $4$ on affinoid algebras and rigid spaces. But I assume that the terminology was chosen in such a way that the affinoid sets in the sense of Chapter 2 later produce affinoid spaces in the sense of Chapters $3$ and $4$ (i.e. in the sense of classical rigid analytic geometry). And indeed, Example $4.3.2$ in the book says that any affinoid $F$ subset of $\mathbb P ^1$ can be identified with the affinoid space $Sp(\mathcal O (F))$.

> > Does this mean that the rigid projective line $\mathbb P ^1$ is an affinoid rigid analytic space?

The answer probably being "no", why did Fresnel and Van der Put choose the call the sets defined in Chapter 2 "affinoid"?

Comment: It is certainly not affinoid for the same reason the scheme is not affine. For example, you can compute that all morphisms $\mathbb{P}^{1,\mathrm{an}}_k\to \mathbb{A}^{1,\mathrm{an}}_k$ are constant (let's assume that $k=\widehat{\overline{k}}$). This of course implies that $\mathcal{O}({\mathbb{P}^{1,\mathrm{an}}_k})=k$ and thus, if it were affinoid, it would be $\mathrm{Sp}(k)$ which, of course, it's not. They probably just included it there to illustrate how you could glue affinoids together.

Comment: Thanks for the argument showing that it's not affinoid! And yes, it is nice to see an example of gluing affinoids together, but it is extremely misleading to suggest that the resulting space is then affinoid as well... The tie-in to Chapters $3$ and $4$ thus kind of collapses, which I find strange...